# What is the most efficient way to ask a MethodInfo how many parameters it takes?

Tags: c#, performance, reflection, methodinfo

What is the most efficient way to ask a MethodInfo if it accepts parameters and, if so, how many?

My current solutions would be: `methodInfo.GetParameters().Any()` and `methodInfo.GetParameters().Count()`.

Is this the most efficient way?

Since I don't actually need any of the `ParameterInfo` objects, is there a way to do this without a call to `GetParameters()`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The two you listed are for LINQ. `Any()` returns `bool` - stating that there is at least one. `Count()` is used any on `IEnumerable<T>`.

`Length` (the property) will be the fastest because `GetParameters()` returns `ParameterInfo[]`.

It does not appear that `MethodInfo` have any other way to access the number of parameters other than `GetParameters()`.

Comment: Are you familiar with MethodImplAttributes or do you know if they could be used to determine this?

Comment: I am not personally. It does not look like it applies.

Comment: @smartcaveman: `MethodImplAttributes` specifies method *implementation* details. As Daniel correctly assumed, it has nothing to do with the number of method parameters.

Answer (score 5):

If efficiency matters why don't you just cache the result in a `Dictionary<MethodInfo,int>`? That way you only need to use reflection only once.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the count of parameters of a `MethodInfo`, then use the below code

```
int intLength = mi.GetParameters().Length; // where mi is a variable of type MethodInfo
```