# c# parameter values to string?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

ok, I'm sure i'm not the only one that has wondered this =)

In a nutshell, is it possible using VisualStudio to convert:

```
string a1, string a2, string a3, string a4, string a5, string  a6
```

into a string sorta like:

```
"'value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4', 'value5', value6'"
```

(don't worry about the exact formatting, i can handle that myself)?

Background:
I often have functions that calls stored procedures that accept a lot of params, and sometimes (debugging) i need to build the "exec dbo.storedprocname param1, param2...." string and run it directly against the server.  Currently i have to manually build the string and i'm hoping there's an easy way to print it out in the immediate window in VisualStudio

**EDIT** (By popular demand):
I'm using Linq2SQL (yes, i knwo it's obsolete) and have 100+ SP's in it. When I need to debug a function, i put a break inside one of these functions to see what it's about to pass to the database. So this would be RUNTIME.  When it hits the breakpoint:

```
public static void MethodCreatedByLINQ2Sql(string param1, string param2, string param3, ...)
{
    context.mystoredprocedure(param1, param2, param3...); //<---breakpoint
}
```

I want to somehow (without having to specify each param), print out a delimited string that i can cut & paste into SSMS2008 (trying to save time) to build a string like this

```
exec dbo.mystoredprocedure [['value1', 'value2', 'value3'......]] <--- pasted value from VisualStudio
```

No, i'm not trying to do SQLInjections or anything like that. I'm just trying to save time - some of these SP's have 20+ params.

Comment: Have you ever heard of a `List<string>`?

Comment: You shouldn't be building SQL queries as strings.  You should be using parameterized queries.  Using `exec` is particularly dangerous and should be avoided whenever possible.

Comment: Surely your methods eventually build the SQL string to execute?

Comment: If you're just looking to get the actual raw query being sent to the SQL server then attaching a profiler to the SQL instance might yield better results.  Regardless of what's going on in the code, it'll show you exactly what the SQL instance receives.

Comment: Do you mean during design time or run time ?

Comment: i'll add more to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you're after?

`String paramStr = String.Format("'{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}', '{4}'", a1, a2, a3,a4,a5);`

I should point out that sending strings like this to the DB can result in [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

**Option 2:**

To print the to the intermediate window you can use this trick:

1. Create a breakpoint
2. Right-Click the red dot -> "When Hit".
3. In the new screen select the "Print a message" checkbox
4. In the textbox type the String.Format from above but with a curly brace on each side:

`{ String.Format(.....) }`

More about the params you can print in that message: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/232dxah7.aspx

Comment: Sorry blach, but this is exactly what i'm trying to avoid.  I'm hoping there is some command that i can run (maybe using reflector??) that if i put a breakpoint on any given function, i can print out a delimited list of values currently passed to that function (in the string.format you provided would be cool).

Comment: You can do the following: Create a breakpoint, Right-Click the red dot -> "When Hit". In the new screen select the "Print a message" checkbox and in the text type the String.Format from above but with a curly brace on each side: { String.Format(.....) }   If this is what you want let me know and I'll update the answer. This will print to the Intermediate screen...

Comment: First off, the "When hit.." option is pretty cool - i didn't know it existed, so i played with it a little. Problem #1 is i still have to type the list of params (or copy the list of params from the function, paste it, remove the datatypes.....). Problem #2 this option isn't in VS2010 Express (*cry*).  This maybe be the closest solution though.

Comment: it's not what i wanted, but it'll work for now.  thanks dude.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the best method is use [`params`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx) in your method to make it more simple:

```
public static void MethodCreatedByLINQ2Sql(params string[] list)
{
    //And then very simply use String.Join()
    string s = String.Join(",", list);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run code in immediate window of visual studio while you debugging.

Comment: right - i'm hoping in the immediate window i can produce the delimited string of values passed to the function; not sure how.

Comment: how can you do that? What do you mean when you say run the code in the immediate window?

Comment: well, i found this SO post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4949503) and by using something like "myFunction.Method.GetParameters()" - it will list your function and a list of datatypes.  In the same post someone suggests "myFunction.Method.GetParameters()[index].Name", but that's not working for me.  Maybe there is something there?

Comment: I think you can get values of parameters only if get access to managed stack I think it only possible by utilizing advantage debugger extensions like SOS

Answer (score 0):

`String.Join()` allows you to concatenate any number of strings, like this:

```
string completeString = String.Join(", ", a1, a2, a3, ... ,aN);
```

this overload (it has 5 different ones) is `.Join(string separator, params object[] values)`

Of course, as already pointed out, this should be avoided, *especially* when you have to use `EXEC`. A parameterized query is highly advisable (but another topic entirely, plus you can easily find many examples around SO itself).

Comment: I would throw in a notice that the best overloads didn't make it in until .NET 4.

Comment: By playing with the separator, you can also add the single quote that encloses each values.

Comment: @ChaosPandion Interesting, I wasn't aware of that.

Answer (score 0):

Have a1, a2 in a string array :

```
var a = new string[] { a1, a2, a3... };
```

Then convert their values to a string this way :

```
var v = string.Join("','", a);
```

Anyway, I would suggest to use Parameter against your stored procedure. The trick above is not clean to generate sql queries because it can lead to SQL injections.

Answer (score 0):

If you run the SQL Profiler it will show you the EXEC statements with all the information you need.  You will have to play around with which options in the Profiler work best for you but generally if you use the TSQL_SPs template it should give you the information you are looking for.

Of course, the limitation to this is that you won't get the string until after the stored procedure call is made so if you put a breakpoint in your code it will have to be after the call to SQL Server.